# Running Bot emulator through docker containers

Tags: docker, botframework

I have a working bot that interacts normally with the bot emulator.When I added docker support the emulator stopped interacting with the bot.

I read that I should un check the "bypass ngrok for local addresses" in the emulator settings and configure ngrok.

I have trouble understanding what I should do, I downloaded ngrok.exe and it opened a command line under the name "ngrok.exe".

The path for the running project is :"http://localhost:32768/api/messages".

How should I configure ngrok so the emulator will start interacting with the bot ?

Any other approaches would be good to..

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with 'docker support'? It is possible to run your bot code locally using Docker and to connect locally with the bot emulator. This is not something you will need ngrok for.

Comment: @Mick the problem is that the messages don't pass through to the bot once I am runing it through docker.By 'docker support' I just mean runing it through docker (when you right click a project in VS there is "Add docker support" and that's what I was refering to, once I did this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my docker container to work with my emulator finally, so I'll show you what I had to change to get it to work!
Using: Emulator 4.2.1, ngrok, and a sample echo bot:

Place the ngrok.exe file where you can find it. Mine's in a folder on my desktop. Then open the emulator. In the bottom left, there is a cog wheel for the emulator settings:

[image: EMULATOR SETTINGS COG]

That page will open ... emulator settings. In this page, use the browse button to navigate to and select your ngrok.exe file:

[image: ngrok path]

I found that it did not matter for me whether or not I checked the 'Bypass' box.

> Note (here's what saved me): localhost is mapped to my ipv4

I ran ipconfig /all in my command prompt to get my IPv4, and then went back to the emulator. In the configuration for my bot, where I was supposed to put in my end point (typically https://localhost:3978/api/messages), I replaced the word 'localhost' with my IPv4:

[image: replaced localhost]

After I did that, I was able to talk to my bot:

[image: Docker Echo]